# Prolog counting

Tags: count, prolog

I'm trying to learn Prolog and I've bumped into an problem. How can I count the number of vertices and edges in a graph that is represented like this:

```
G=[1-[2],2-[3],3-[4],4-[1]]
```

I know that there is a function `aggregate_all` but I don't know what the correct parameters will be to resolve this.

Comment: What is the result suppose to be? Right now to answer this I would have to guess.

Comment: What graph does your example represent?

Comment: G=[1-[2],2-[3],3-[4],4-[1]] this is the graph representation, which is a directed graph.(1-[2] -> edge from 1 to 2). And I want to count the number of vertices and edges of a graph represented in this form.

Comment: Please show us what your desired predicate should look like.

Comment: So i need a function that receives the above graph and returns the number of edges and vertices

Comment: Then you need to switch to another language. There are no functions in Prolog.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a learning exercise I'll post a partial answer to get started: The list is formatted strangely, but it is acutally just a mapping of nodes to their successing nodes (connected through edges), thereby representing nodes and edges of the graph at the same time. That means that you can just count the nodes and edges as the members of lists they are. For example the nodes you can count with:

```
countNodes([], 0).
countNodes([_-[_]|T], Cnt) :- countNodes(T, Cnt1), Cnt is Cnt1 + 1.
```

(I added the pattern of each list entry to demonstrate how you would access their parts. `[_|T]` would work, too). Now this is assuming that every node appears left once in the list, with a list of all its successors. If that is not the case, you would have count the unique elements of the list (The example you give is more a ring than a graph, so it is hard to tell).

Counting the edges works similarly. In that case you will have to sum the element counts of the right sides of all elements of this main list. In the pattern above, that would be the sum of the lengths of all `L`s in `[_-L]`. If you want your predicate (not function) to result in both counts of edges and nodes, you can easily use two parameters, or combine the result in one, e.g. initializing the result in the recursion anchor with `countNodes([], counts(0,0))`.

Edit - Follow up: Solution for counting edges:

```
countEdges([], 0).
countEdges([_-Edges|T], Cnt) :- countEdges(T, Cnt1), length(Edges ,L), Cnt is Cnt1 + L.
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Since you advised that this is a strange representation... can you advise what will be the approach to count the edges if we have a graph represented like this : ([a,b,c,d,e],[e(a,b),e(a,d),e(a,e),e(b,e),e(e,c)]) ?

Comment: @Qs13 With strange I meant that the `-` is a little confusing to read. The representation is fine for a graph, only some predicates may get a little more complex. Flattening it like you just did makes the counting easier: Instead of counting the elements in a list of lists, you just count the elements of the first list for nodes and the second list for edges. The predefined predicate [length/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=length/2) will do it if you don't want to implement it for practice.

Comment: Oh, I understand, so if i stick to the initial representation and i computed the below:
length_lst([], 0 ).
length_lst([_|Rest] , L ) :- length_lst(Rest,N) , L is N+1 . 
to find the length of a list, how can i combine this with the response provided by you to receive the number of edges. I tried a couple of things but without success. Many thanks

Comment: You replace `_` with a head element `[N-Edges]` and add the length of the list Edges in every step.

Comment: countEdges([N-[Edges]|T], Cnt) :- countEdges(T, Cnt1), Cnt is Cnt1 + list_length([Edges] ,L). tried this but didn't went as planned

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and explanations !